# Why I get PLS-00049: bad bind variable in Apex

Tags: oracle, sequence

I am trying to auto generate PK values for table **Movie**, but get this error when creating trigger

```
Compilation failed, line 2 (10:45:07) The line numbers associated with compilation errors 
are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database 
triggers.
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.MOVIE_ID'
```

This is trigger code

```
create or replace trigger "MOVIE_T1"
BEFORE
insert on "Movie"
for each row
begin
    :new.MOVIE_ID := MOVIE_PK_SEQ.nextval;
end;
```

This is sequence code

```
CREATE SEQUENCE   "MOVIE_PK_SEQ"  
MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999 
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 
NOCACHE  NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL
```

I definitely have column **MOVIE_ID** on my **MOVIE** table

Comment: `:new."MOVIE_ID" := "MOVIE_PK_SEQ".nextval;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current issue is related to your column's (`MOVIE_ID`) definition within the table, that should be quoted(`"MOVIE_ID"`) as Lukasz as already pointed out.

Your DB version should be `12+`, since `NOKEEP` option for `CREATE SEQUENCE` doesn't exists till `12c`.

In `Oracle DB` version `12c`, a sequence's next value might be set as default for a column

(*Trigger is not needed*) :

```
alter table "Movie" modify "MOVIE_ID" default "MOVIE_PK_SEQ".nextval not null
```

if the table was not created yet, you could do :

```
create table "Movie"
(
  "MOVIE_ID"  int generated always as identity,
  ...
```

without need of a creation of seperate sequence by you (Oracle does this for you)